# iPhone UITableView Nested

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create a screen for an iPhone app. My screen currently looks like this:

http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/accordion-uitableview.png

The tutorial I am following can be obtained here:

http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/expandable-collapsable-accordio-uitableview/

The tutorial got me to a point where I have:

1) Top items
2) Sub items

When the user presses a Top item, assuming it has sub items, it will expand to show the sub items.

My question:

How would I further extend this tutorial so I can have another layer e.g. the sub items to expand with further information. So essentially I will have three layers:

1) Top items
2) Sub items
3) Sub-sub items.

So that when the user presses the sub item, it will expand to show all the sub-sub items.

A perfect answer would be a step by step instruction on how to continue from the tutorial, the source code can be obtained from the link above (scroll to the bottom for the Github location). Otherwise, please tell me if my approach is wrong and there is another way. I am completely new to objective c, so please try to be as precise as possible.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reproduce what they did for one more layer.  Glancing over the tutorial quickly, they have a custom UITableViewCell for the parent, and a separate one for the child.  When you tap a parent, the table is reloaded with new rows inserted under the parent containing the children; and using the child cell types.

You need to create a "secondLevelChild" cell type to have a different look so it's obvious that it is a third level.

Then handle the touch events to know if you are touching a 1st level child and need to expand the 3rd level.